# IvyDe transitive dependencies restriction

Tags: eclipse, ivyde

Because we have a large number of dependencies, we prefer to have our developers only use direct dependencies of our project.

i'm looking for a way to automatically enforce this. Eclipse access rules come to mind, but they would need to be manually added as far as i can tell.

i understand i can make ivyDE not resolve transitive dependencies but this would lead to problems with the 3th party jars that actually need the transitive depedency.

Does anyone have a working system to enforce this (or possibly some way of generating access restrictions on the ivyDe container with a ant-/shell script)